# Should the filter capacity be matched to the brew amount?

Tags: drip-brew, paper-filter

I understand the of course the filter must be able to contain at least the amount of grounds for the cups you intend to brew.

However, I am using an [8-12 cup machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001K66LPQ) even though I live alone and generally only make 2-4 cups in the morning (sometimes 6 if I take some to work). [My filters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UBNRH6) are thus also that size. I use [this coffee.](https://www.cajungrocer.com/french-market-coffee-chicory-creole-roast.html?cvsfa=1338&cvsfe=2&cvsfhu=31373436&gclid=CjwKEAiA1o-zBRDomsWasvKh4S8SJADSlZkqf7B2ikYJXNaZM92s0zvKEDCUUrQrKSJVR8N_K2JtzRoCLBzw_wcB)

After a recent trip to India and having enjoyed [filter coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_filter_coffee), I started paying a bit more attention to try to get closer to that style (hence the chicory coffee).

1. Compression appears to be key for this style of coffee. With a flat-bottom, 8-12 cup filter with only 3 tbsp of grounds, the grounds appear to be very loose (obviously).
2. I then try to stamp it down a bit with the tablespoon, but this makes the layer quite thin in my very non-expert opinion.
3. After the brewing is done and I dispose of the filter, I notice that there is a hole in the middle of the grounds where you can directly see the filter (no hole through the filter itself).

I'm not so picky about taste, but this made me think that perhaps such a wide filter may not be suited for the small amounts I'm brewing. Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree with you.  With the thin flat layer of coffee the hot water is just pushing a hole right through it.  You are not getting nearly the contact time of a full size brew.

If it was conical or V shaped filter then it would better accommodate different size batches.

On that pot it does not look like you could just simply use a different filter size.

Comment: sad. thanks, so if i'm understanding you correctly, my options would be to use more ground + brew more such that the water doesn't create a hole fully through, or buy a new coffeemaker either matches my regular brew amount or can host a smaller cup size?

Comment: Basically yes.   Maybe you could find an insert for the drip mechanism.

Comment: A reach but put two filter in and a little more coffee but same water.  The two filter will slow down the flow rate.  I have a degree in chemical engineering.  What does it hurt to give it a try.  You cold even reuse the clean filter once as the dirty filter.